# Unable to create Triggers in Azure Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, azure

I have a MySQL Database running in azure. I have been trying to create some very basic trigger which I have tested on a local instance of MySQL which worked like they where supposed to do.

However, It doesn't seem like an option to create triggers in Azure's MySQL database.

```
> CREATE TRIGGER update_last_modified_xxx
-> BEFORE UPDATE ON xxx
->     FOR EACH ROW
-> BEGIN
->     SET new.last_modified = NOW();
-> END;
->


(1419, 'You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)') (edited)
```

And changing `log_bin_trust_function_creators` is not possible due to the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-limits) set by MS. Am I missing something here or should it be possible to create triggers in a MySQL DB running in azure?

Answer (score 4):

I've simply set the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` parameter 'ON' by hand from 'Server Parameters' tab in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) and solved the issue.

Comment: I've also succesfully added a trigger to my MySql database.

Comment: This also worked perfectly for me. And as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-server-parameters#log_bin_trust_function_creators) it should not cause any problems either.

Answer (score 2):

In Azure Database for MySQL, binary logs are always enabled (i.e. log_bin is set to ON). In case you want to use triggers you will get error similar to you do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable).

The binary logging format is always ROW and all connections to the server ALWAYS use row-based binary logging. With row-based binary logging, security issues do not exist and binary logging cannot break, so you can safely set log_bin_trust_function_creators to TRUE.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-server-parameters#log_bin_trust_function_creators

Answer (score 0):

From [Online migration issues & limitations to Azure DB for MySQL with Azure Database Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/known-issues-azure-mysql-online)

> Schema in target Azure Database for MySQL must not have any triggers.

So I don't think the Azure service allows triggers.

Comment: So essentially they are forcing one to migrate to MS SQL

Comment: There's no forcing of anything. Azure Database for MySQL is DBaaS, and has specific features and limitations. There are limitations to SQL Database (SQL Server as-a-service) as well. If you need features not available in DBaaS, you can run a VM / container instance of MySQL - no need to go to SQL Server.